# Prove that: $(f^{-1})' (y)= \frac 1{[f'(f^{-1}(y))]}$ for all $y \in f((a,b))$

Tags: analysis

I have that $f$ has an inverse function $f^{-1} : f((a,b)) \to (a,b)$. I have proven that $f^{-1}$ will be differentiable on $f((a,b))$ so I don't need that part, but I want to prove that: $$(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac 1{[f'(f^{-1}(y))]}$$ holds for all $y \in f((a,b))$.

Comment: How did you prove that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable without explicitly finding the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity I will use f[y] to mean the "evaluation of $f$ at the point $y$".

Clearly $(f\circ f^{-1} )[y] = y$ for all $y$. Therefore
$$(f \circ f^{-1})'[y] = 1$$
By the chain rule :
$$(f \circ f^{-1})'[y] = f'[f^{-1}[y]] \cdot (f^{-1})'[y].$$

Hence
$$ 1 = f'[f^{-1}[y]] \cdot (f^{-1})'[y].$$